# systemd service to start after mount of ram drive

Tags: mount, fstab, systemd-unit, systemd-mount

I have a inotify-based service that  backs up my LAN's git directory to the Dropbox. I tried keeping the git directory in the Dropbox but I have multiple git clients so often get error files there.

In this early stage of development, this is a fairly busy and chatty system service that wants to log to a ram drive. I don't want to use `/tmp` because other applications depend on having space there.

To create the ram drive in my fstab I have this :

```
 tmpfs       /mnt/ram tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=1024M   0 0
```

I need to be sure that the ram drive is mounted before the backup service starts. I want to put a condition to the service that delays its start.

I see suggestions that people use the `*.mnt` service as a precondition but I don't see any file in `/lib/systemd/system` that gives me the name of the service I need.

How can I identify this mount? Is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Arch, at least, systemd mounts generated from `/etc/fstab` are deployed to `/run/systemd/generator`

For example on my system, with the listing below I can add to my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=backup logging to temp 
After=mnt-ram.mount
```

*ls -la /run/systemd/generator*

```
:> ls -la
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 362 Jun 20 17:01 -.mount
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 260 Jun 20 17:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 580 Jun 21 04:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 516 Jun 20 17:01 boot.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 120 Jun 20 17:01 local-fs.target.requires
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  80 Jun 20 17:01 local-fs.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 168 Jun 20 17:01 mnt-3T.automount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 515 Jun 20 17:01 mnt-3T.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 168 Jun 20 17:01 mnt-4T.automount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 515 Jun 20 17:01 mnt-4T.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 260 Jun 20 17:01 mnt-ram.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 349 Jun 20 17:01 mnt-sda.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  80 Jun 20 17:01 remote-fs.target.requires
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your situation, you have written a systemd service file to load your self-made backup service. Now you want to ensure that the ram drive mount (defined by an entry in /etc/fstab) is available before the backup service starts.

I haven't done this myself, i just looked it up in a man page. So this might or might not work.

According to `man systemd.unit`, in "[UNIT] SECTION OPTIONS", there is a switch that looks promising:

> RequiresMountsFor=
>
> Takes a space-separated list of absolute paths. Automatically adds dependencies of type Requires= and After= for all mount units required to access the specified path.
>
> Mount points marked with noauto are not mounted automatically through local-fs.target, but are still honored for the purposes of this option, i.e. they will be pulled in by this unit.

For testing purpose, you could add `noauto` to your `fstab`. If this works, your ram drive should be mounted automatically after reboot - if it's configured as dependency of your backup service.